# compare the next row value and change the current row value using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

any way of comparing a row value with the next row value and change the current row value using pandas?

Basically in the the first Data frame DF1, in the value column, one of the value is '999', so the values of the next rows for that 'user-id' is less than the value '999'. so in this case i want to add '1000' which is 10^(len(999)) to the all successive values of that 'user-id'.

I tried using shift, but I found that it skips one of the row value by giving a 'Null'. And I am also not sure how to do it without creating a new value.

For example,
if this is the data set I have, DF1

```
user-id      serial-number       value     day

1   2   10      1
1   2   20      2
1   2   30      3
1   2   40      4
1   2   50      5
1   2   60      6
1   2   70      7
1   2   80      8
1   2   90      9
1   2   100    10
1   2   999    11
1   2   300    12
1   2   400    13
2   3   11      1
2   3   12      2
2   3   13      3
2   3   14      4
2   3   99      5
2   3   16      6
2   3   17      7
2   3   18      8
```

I need the resultant data frame to be DF1:

```
user-id     serial-number    value      day

1   2     10     1
1   2     20     1
1   2     30     1
1   2     40     1
1   2     50     1
1   2     60     1
1   2     70     1
1   2     80     1
1   2     90     1 
1   2     100    1 
1   2     999    1 
1   2     1300   1
1   2     1400   1
.   .
2   3     11     1
2   3     12     1
2   3     13     1
2   3     14     1
2   3     99     1
2   3     116    1
2   3     117    1
2   3     118    1
```

I think I've explained the question properly.

similarly i want to do it for all the values in the "value" column for each user ID.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 methods for this:

This method we multiply by the max value of each user-id - it works on the sample dataset you porivded but it might not work overal.

```
df.set_index('user-id', inplace=True)
df['value'] += df.groupby('user-id')['value'].apply(
lambda x:(x.shift() > x).astype(int).cumsum()
) * 10**df.groupby('user-id')['value'].max().apply(lambda x: len(str(x)))
```

The other on is looping through each item:

```
def foo(x):
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        if x.iloc[i] < x.iloc[i-1]:
            x.iloc[i:] = x.iloc[i:] + 10**(len(str(x.iloc[i-1])))
    return x

df['value'] = df.groupby('user-id')['value'].apply(foo)
```